# How can I print a PID in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I tried to:

```
pid = spawn fn -> 1 + 2 end
IO.puts(pid)
IO.puts(IO.inspect(pid))
```

and both given a

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for #PID<0.59.0>
```

There must be a way to get the "#PID<0.59.0>" representation of the `pid`, since the REPL prints that `#PID<0.59.0>`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `IO.inspect` in a call to `IO.puts`. Simply calling `IO.inspect` will do what you're looking for.

```
pid = spawn fn -> 1 + 2 end
IO.inspect(pid)
```

Answer (score 15):

I found that I'm using the wrong `inspect`, there is [`IO.inspect/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2) and [`Kernel.inspect/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2). The second works for me:

```
pid = spawn fn -> 1 + 2 end
IO.puts(inspect(pid))
```

Comment: You can print most anything using `inspect`. `IO.inspect` is just `IO.puts(Kernel.inspect(x))`

Answer (score 8):

When you want to append it to a string (to display some extra details), you can use string interpolation:

```
pid = spawn(fn -> 1 + 2 end)
IO.puts "Pid: #{inspect pid}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use self()

`pid = self() 
 IO.inspect(pid)`